# Efficient and fastest way to search in a list of strings

Tags: python, algorithm, list, search, time-complexity

The following function return the number of words from a list that contain the exact same characters as the word entered. The order of the characters in the words is not important. However, say there is a list that contain millions of words. What is the most efficient and fastest way to perform this search?

**Example:**

```
words_list = ['yek','lion','eky','ekky','kkey','opt'];
```

if we were to match the word "key" with the words in the list, the function only return "yek" and "eky" since they share the same exact characters with "key" regardless of the order.

**Below is the function I wrote**

```
def find_a4(words_list, word):
    # all possible permutations of the word that we are looking for
    # it's a set of words 
    word_permutations = set([''.join(p) for p in permutations(word)])
    word_size = len(word)
    count = 0

    for word in word_list:
        # in the case of word "key", 
        # we only accept words that have 3 characters 
        # and they are in the word_permutations 
        if len(word) == word_size and word in word_permutations:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: `[k for k in word_list if sorted('key') == sorted(list(k))]`

Comment: Try sorting the letters of the input word and all the words in the list. Therefore, 'yek', 'eky', 'key' becomes 'key'. They are anagrams.

Comment: Sorting every word? I think that we will make it worst ....

Comment: @data-oil you have 2 options, sort all the words, or store them in a `collections.Counter`, then do the comparisons

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: How to implement the 2nd option please?

Comment: this is a duplicate, just lost in the sea of those word search questions.

Comment: `def find_a4(words_list, word):
    word = sorted(word);
    return sum(1 for w in words_list if sorted(w) == word)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary whose key is the sorted version of the word:

```
word_list = ['yek','lion','eky','ekky','kkey','opt']

from collections import defaultdict
word_index = defaultdict(set)

for word in word_list:
    idx = tuple(sorted(word))
    word_index[idx].add(word)

# word_index = {
#    ('e', 'k', 'y'): {'yek', 'eky'},
#    ('i', 'l', 'n', 'o'): {'lion'},
#    ('e', 'k', 'k', 'y'): {'kkey', 'ekky'},
#    ('o', 'p', 't'): {'opt'}
# }
```

Then for querying you would do:

```
def find_a4(word_index, word):
    idx = tuple(sorted(word))
    return len(word_index[idx])
```

Or if you need to return the actual words, change it to `return word_index[idx]`.

Efficiency: querying runs [in average in O(1) time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Nice solution. Note `frozenset` would work equally well.

Comment: If you want to take this approach, you should use a `Counter` instead of `defaultdict`, no need to store all the words, just store the count

Answer (score 2):

For large string, you will have `n!` permutations to search. I will sort all the strings before comparison, this will be nlog(n), and will sort and compare only when lengths match -

```
def find_a4(words_list, word):
    word = ''.join(sorted(word))
    word_size = len(word)
    count = 0
    for word1 in words_list:
        if len(word1) == word_size:
            if word == ''.join(sorted(word1)):
                count += 1
    return count
```